# LARAVEL use Lists result as a parameter

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I need some help to do this query in laravel.

```
Select id from tableone where id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

The (1,2,3,4,5) must be a result from another query.

```
 This >>> $s = TableOne::lists('id');
 Result >>> ["4","14", "11", "1", "13", "3", "2"]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: In Laravel 5.3 `lists` will be deprecated. It has been renamed to `pluck`. Use `pluck` instead for future proofing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wherein` function in Laravel.

```
$s = AnotherTable::lists('id'); // get ids from another query
$users = TableOne::whereIn('id', $s)->get(); // pass array of ids into it
```

For more information: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects